# Pytest-django: cannot delete db after tests

Tags: python, django, database, pytest, pytest-django

I have a Django application, and I'm trying to test it using `pytest` and `pytest-django`. However, quite often, when the tests finish running, I get the error that the database failed to be deleted: `DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.`

Basically, the minimum test code that I could narrow it down to is:

```
@pytest.fixture
def make_bundle():
    a = MyUser.objects.create(key_id=uuid.uuid4())
    return a


class TestThings:
    def test_it(self, make_bundle):
        all_users = list(MyUser.objects.all())
        assert_that(all_users, has_length(1))
```

Every now and again the tests will fail with the above error. Is there something I am doing wrong? Or how can I fix this?

The database that I am using is PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Yeah, pytest-django does not play nice with PostgreSQL when running tests against a production DB *that is in use.* I have been reading Two Scoops of Django and trying to figure out the optimal PostgreSQL "shadow DB" setup for testing but I am not there yet. Just wanted to let you know I'm in the same boat!!

Comment: @ScottSkiles The thing is that it is not the production database, it is a database that is being created and dropped for the test runs.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer because I need to post a chunk of code and because this worked. However, this looks like a dirty hack to me, and I'll be more than happy to accept anybody else's answer if it is better.
Here's my solution: basically, add the raw sql that kicks out all the users from the given db to the method that destroys the db. And do that by monkeypatching. To ensure that the monkeypatching happens before tests, add that to the root `conftest.py` file as an autouse fixture:

```
def _destroy_test_db(self, test_database_name, verbosity):
    """
    Internal implementation - remove the test db tables.
    """
    # Remove the test database to clean up after
    # ourselves. Connect to the previous database (not the test database)
    # to do so, because it's not allowed to delete a database while being
    # connected to it.
    with self.connection._nodb_connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) "
            "FROM pg_stat_activity "
            "WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '{}' "
                "AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();".format(test_database_name)
        )

        cursor.execute("DROP DATABASE %s"
                       % self.connection.ops.quote_name(test_database_name))


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_db_cleanup():
    creation.BaseDatabaseCreation._destroy_test_db = _destroy_test_db
```

Note that the kicking-out code may depend on your database engine, and the method that needs monkeypatching may be different in different Django versions.

Comment: What is `creation` variable here?

Comment: @bcollins Sorry, I don't remember now